# How to reset setting of an application in windows

Tags: windows-8.1, proxy

Previously i had set global proxy using 
netsh winhttp set proxy :

and also set the same proxy in internet options settings.
It was working fine but few days later i changed my proxy and did the same steps previously mentioned.

Most of the application have started using the new proxy but few application are still using the old proxy address, how do i reset their setting or how to override any global setting and then setting proxy again.

ex: vyprvpnservices.exe using the old proxy instead of new one, svchost.exe uses old proxy but then switch back to new proxy if connection fails.

OS: Windows 8.1 x64

Comment: I have already uninstalled that (vyprvpn) application using IObit Uninstaller and installed it again but it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

From the admin command prompt run:
`netsh winhttp reset proxy`

Then, in Control Panel > Internet Options > Connections (tab):
Remove all connections

Restart the computer.

Verify settings are correct, and that no proxy is being used.

Add the new proxy.

Comment: it didn't help.
I think the old proxy is cached somewhere and windows system services still referring to that values. With new proxy My internet connection is working fine and there is no problem in windows update as well, can't figure out where it has stored and how to disable/change it