# NETSH + WSL2: revert netsh-command and gain back WSL2-networking capabilities

Tags: networking, wsl2, netsh

Following [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1717753/how-to-connect-to-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-another-machine-within-networ) I issued this command as an admin thorough PowerShell:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=4000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=4000 connectaddress=(wsl hostname -i)
```

Unfortunately, I know zero about `netsh` and blindly ran code I don't understand.

Now, in my alpine WSL2 I cannot `apk update`:

```
~# apk update
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: updating https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main: Permission denied
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: updating https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community: Permission denied
v20231219-2427-gd0dda5e6861 [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main]
v20231219-2427-gd0dda5e6861 [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community]
0 unavailable, 2 stale; 23217 distinct packages available
```

---

First suggestion was to, as far as I understand, reset the proxy as [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/839909/how-to-reset-setting-of-an-application-in-windows)

1. This question addresses another issue not related to WSL2 and the answer is for Win8.
2. I am hesitant of running `netsh winhttp reset proxy` as this computer's proxy was setup by someone else and the machine needs to keep that configuration. Also, Windows itself has no problem talking to the internet. The command might reset a setting, but it will also do more that reverting only one command: it might revert even thousands of them.
3. Under Control Panel > Internet Options > Connections (tab) I see no connections to delete.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset setting of an application in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/839909/how-to-reset-setting-of-an-application-in-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address reverting the `netsh`-command I learned that

1. `netsh interface portproxy ...` is used to set up a port forwarding rule
2. I can check all such rules with `netsh interface portproxy show all`. In my case I found:

```
Abfragen auf ipv4:             Verbinden mit ipv4:

Adresse         Anschluss   Adresse         Anschluss
--------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
...
0.0.0.0         4000        127.0.1.1       4000
...
```

`127.0.1.1` is what `wsl.exe hostname -i` gives as an output.

3. I can delete this rule with the following command

```
netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=4000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0
```

4. This deletes all rules with listenport=4000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 and "reverts"

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=4000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=4000 connectaddress=(wsl hostname -i)
```

Now, addressing the WSL2-networking capabilities, I have to say that this is related to the Windows firewall. See:
https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/11824

Using a different internet connection solved it.